# Push notifications with subscription for categories

Tags: javascript, notification

We have an application for viewing the documents for different products. I would like users to subscribe for any product which they use. They have to be notified when any new guide is published for that particular product.

We tried service workers. But it looks like, it will only allow users to subscribe to the entire site and provide notifications for any content newly added to the site.

I need subscription to products not to the entire site. Which tool will help to achieve this?

**Requirement:**

1. User can subscribe to one/more products
2. So, when user has subscribed to product A and is now viewing a document about product B. He should be asked to subscribe to B(since he has not subscribed). But when he is on a guide for product A, he should not be asked to subscribe(since he has already subscribed).
3. I should be able to provide javascript code to tell the system whenever a new guide is being published.

Answer (score 1):

Firebase, it allows you to send push notifications which can include payloads (any data or other information along with the push notification), maybe it includes a message letting the user know they should subscribe to a product?

I have used it both in app and outside of the app to subscribe users to global topics and allow specific users to subscribe to the topic of their choice.
"Topics" - strings defining the name of a subscription, 
one way to allow users to opt in and out of subscriptions.
The rest of your requirements can be met with the right conditionals.
If you need more help or have any questions, feel free to ask.